# How to change the 'Section' title and its arrangement in a LaTeX document

Tags: sectioning, document-configuration

I am handing in an assignment that is structured by exercises, rather than sections. I have already written my responses using the `\section{}` command and would now like to structure the final output by exercises rather than sections. Concretely, I want the number to appear to the right of each exercise: *Exercise 4* instead of *4 Section title*.

I have been able to find information on how to do this for chapters and many other document parts here on SE, but strangely not for sections.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section{Exercise} % First exercise

\section{Exercise} % Second exercise

\section{Exercise} % Third exercise

\end{document}
```

Produces this:

[image: MWE]

Now all I really need to do is reverse the order from `# Section title` to `Section title #` because my section title is *exercise*. Also, ideally, the section numbering would be in roman numerals, while subsections remain as originally formatted.

Comment: This depends heavily on the underlying document class (and some packages)... Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I think, you should `exsheets` etc. which are defined for such applications

Answer (score 10):

With `article` class as you specified in the MWE, one can employ `titlesec`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{Exercise~\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Exercise} % First exercise

\section{Exercise} % Second exercise

\section{Exercise} % Third exercise

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works also for `scrartcl`. :)

Comment: I want to have my sections with "exercise", but how do I avoid getting "Exercise" when making a section which is not supposed to have it?