# Appendix header on top of a table and numbering

Tags: koma-script, appendix

I am trying to create an appendix to my document. I have two issues. First, the appendix should be labelled as follows:
"Appendix A", followed by "Appendix B", etc. No extra naming. I tried to use `\appendix` and chapters, but that always numbered the appendixes. For example "Appendix A" is shown as "1 Appendix A" instead. Is it possible to have only "Appendix", followed by a letter, in `scrreprt`? Using `section*` does not work as then it will not be listed in the TOC.

I am also trying to put the start of the appendix on top of a table. I found some code recommended in another post but I cannot get it to work. Any help appreciated.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,rotating}  
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter{Intro}
    
    Some text...
    
    \chapter{Main}
    
    \chapter{Conclusion}
    
    \section*{Appendix A}
    
    \section*{Appendix B}
    
    \renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{section}\arabic{table}}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
    \setcounter{table}{0}
    \setcounter{section}{1}
    
    \begingroup
    \newgeometry{bottom=0.1cm, top=0.1cm}
    \vfill
    \begin{table}
    
    \begin{sideways}    
    \begin{minipage}{\textheight} % here
        \caption{A simple table}
        \begin{tabular}{p{5cm}p{5cm}p{5cm}p{5cm}}
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
            10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 & 10000000000 \\
        \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage} % and here
    \end{sideways}
    \end{table}
    \vfill
    \restoregeometry
    \endgroup

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can borrow the main idea from [how to change the section title and its arrangement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245089/how-to-change-the-section-title-and-its-arrangement-in-a-latex-document) and use this in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{Appendix~\thesubsection}{1em}{}
```

You might also like to switch between listing your `\section{}` as Appendix ... on the TOC or including it manually using

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Unnumbered Appendix}
\section*{Unnumbered Appendix}
```

**Important!** Labeling sections in a new way works only if

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{section}\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{section}}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\setcounter{section}{1}
```

is inserted before use of `\section`.

In order to replace Table 1 with Appendix B you need to change both `\tablename` and `\thetable` like this:

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{section}\arabic{table}}
%\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{section}} %if you need a chapter index only
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Appendix}
```

Comment: thanks that answers the first part of my question, but I am still not sure if this is the way to do it with `scrreprt`. Seems like a brute force method. If it works I do not mind though. But I am still looking for a way to have the appendix on top of the page with the table. The appendix text and label can also be smaller than in case of using `\chapter`. In any case I upvoted you for your efforts.

Comment: I'm not sure about that ```titlesec``` package, but that redefinition of ```\thesubsection``` is a standard way as I was instructed on my .TeX workshop this week. If I got it right, you want Table 1 to be replaced with Appendix B. In this case you need to change both ```\tablename``` and ```\thetable```. Check my updated answer.